# Simplified expression of the ratio of this series

Tags: sequences-and-series

I need to simplify the expression of this series:
$$
\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^{n}(4n)!}{1 · 4 · 7 · ⋯ ·3n+1}
$$
As the ratio (for the test): $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

First I multiplied the reciprocal of a(n) by a(n+1):

$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{3^{n+1}(4(n+1))!}{(3(n+1)+1)}\cdot\frac{3n+1}{3^{n}(4n)!}
$$

Then I expanded the terms:

$$
\frac{3^{n+1}\cdot4n!(4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)(3n+1)}{3^{n}\cdot4n!(3n+4)(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)}
$$

Simplified down to:

$$
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{3(4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)}{(3n+4)(3n+3)(3n+2)}
$$

Am I missing a step or performing any incorrectly?

This question is from a practice test, which is multiple choice, but I don't have an answer key:
[See choices here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VGwpR.png)

Comment: I think the term $3n+1$ in the numerator should not be there...

Comment: Why did you wrote $(3(n+1)+1)=(3n+4)(3n+3)(3n+2)(3n+1)$ in your denominator? That is wrong and the right answer is amongst the given. It should be $3(n+1)+1=3n+3+1=3n+4$.

Comment: What is the point of simplifying the terms of a clearly divergent series? $3^n(4n)!$ grows incredibly faster than $(3n+1)!!!$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}&=
\frac{3^{n+1}\cdot4n!(4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)(3n+1)}{3^{n}\cdot 4n!(3n+4)}\\
&=
\frac{3 (4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)(3n+1)}{(3n+4)}.
\end{align}
Answer F.

Answer (score 0):

As I saw, the thing you are missing is in the product of denominators,

In product there is a difference of $3$ in consecutive terms , so when dividing denominator of $a_{n+1}~by ~a_n$ It should be $3n+4$ which is left,because $3n+4$ is the consecutive of $3n+1$ not $(3n+2)(3n+3)(3n+4)$

Numerator is all good , so the answer should be  $$\frac{3 (4n+4)(4n+3)(4n+2)(4n+1)(3n+1)}{(3n+4)}$$ which is option F and how is shown by @PaoloLeonetti

Comment: I had a feeling I messed up the denominator. I mistakenly unpacked it like a factorial. Thanks.